# Calling CryptAcquireContext from C#

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I want to use the 'CryptAcquireContext' WinAPI function in C#.

I have `using System.Runtime.InteropServices`, and I import the DLL in the following manner:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(ref IntPtr hProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, uint dwProvType, uint dwFlags);
```

To call the function, I use the following code:

```
IntPtr handelTest = new IntPtr();
uint CRYPt_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0xF0000000;
uint PROV_RsA_FULL = 1;
bool res = CryptAcquireContext(ref handelTest, null, "MS_ENHANCED_PROV", PROV_RsA_FULL, CRYPt_VERIFYCONTEXT);
if (!res)
{
    int a = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Console.WriteLine("Error in Acqired, CryptAcquireContext function\n");
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Key Context Acquired\n");
```

However, an error occurs and `res==false`.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: A string in c is usually byte[] terminated with a '\0'.  C# a string/char is two byes with a private property which determines if the character is one or two  bytes.  In c# you use Encode method library methods to convert strings to bytes and bytes to string which automatically does the packing/unpacking for one/two bytes.

Comment: when my argument is string, how my change string to bytes, that's ERROR

Comment: @jdweng the `CharSet` property of the DllImportAttribute takes care of that.

Comment: What is the value of `a`?

Comment: a is last error

Comment: How are the strings declared in c++? *char or **char? or something elase.

Comment: CharSet does conversions like linefeeds and returns, not other conversions.

Comment: in this function, in wincrypt.h we have CryptAcquireContext(HCRYPTPROV *, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD)

Comment: LPCSTR is const char*

Comment: We can see how a is assigned. But what is its value.

Comment: MS_ENHANCED_PROV is a #define in wincrypt.h containing the actual provider name but you are quoting it as if it were a string ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a P/Invoke issue. The arguments are just bad, GetLastError (a) is NTE_KEYSET_NOT_DEF / 0x80090019, which is "The requested provider does not exist.".

Pass `null` as the provider name parameter to go on, or use a valid provider name.

However, note I would instead define the function like this (ensure unicode, and the first parameter is `out`, not `ref`):

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(out IntPtr hProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, uint dwProvType, uint dwFlags);
```

Comment: tank you for your help, 1. I change 'ref' and Unicode to 'out' and 'Unicode' 2. in parameter 3, provider name I set "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0", this is successfully,.....